# Python-Change the RGB values under condition after performing K-Means Clustering

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors, k-means

I am performing a K-Means Clustering of color and my goal is to extract the cluster which consists of the darkest color and change the other clusters to consist of bright color, such as white.

However, I got stuck in changing the color in other clusters. Hopes there is someone can help, thaks. Below is some steps I have been performed.

### Read the Image

This is the source of the image
[image: Example Image]

```
img = cv2.imread('./example.png')
```

### Convert it into RGB fromat and reshape

```
img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
rgb=img.reshape((img.shape[0]*img.shape[1],3))
```

### Perform K-Means Clustering

```
optimial_kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 8) 
# I find 8 would be a good number to perform clustering in this case
optimial_kmeans = optimial_kmeans.fit(rgb)
labels=optimial_kmeans.labels_
labels_list=list(labels)
centroid=optimial_kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centroid)
>>> 
[[101.35986159  98.54044118  88.06574394]
 [165.2222611  157.3535294  147.28277564]
 [142.64453028 136.56983743 124.84256329]
 [176.80774583 167.69645434 159.05120078]
 [190.01922264 180.34685256 173.28065061]
 [129.80575344 123.89053238 112.81097395]
 [208.07391793 199.37113547 194.59963463]
 [153.35096011 147.58535105 135.89838453]]
```

### Extract the darkest color cluster index

As you see from the result, in this case, cluster 0 consists of the darkest color, the rgb value of that centroid is `[101.35986159  98.54044118  88.06574394]`, so I would get the index, 0
[image: Cluster Image]

```
r_value = centroid[:,0]
filter_result = np.where(r_value == min(r_value))
hair_index = int(filter_result[0])
print(hair_index)
>>>
0
```

### Kmeans on Image Compression

```
X_compressed = optimial_kmeans.cluster_centers_[optimial_kmeans.labels_]
X_compressed = np.clip(X_compressed.astype('uint8'), 0, 255)
# Reshape to have the same dimension as the original image
compress_img = X_compressed.reshape(img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3)
```

### The part I stuck

If I print the `X_compressed`, I can see the following result:

```
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[129 123 112]
[129 123 112]
[129 123 112]
[129 123 112]
.....
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
[142 136 124]
```

So, it is clear that all the RGB values have changed to the centroid RGB values respective to their cluster.
[image: Image compressed in 8 colours]

As I have mentioned that I just want to keep the darkest color, in this case,[101  98  88], and the other would change to a bright color, [255 255 255], white in RGB representation.

Therefore, I perform the below code, however, it does not work. Instead of replacing [255 255 255] to other, all the value change to [101  98  88].

```
X_compressed[np.where(optimial_kmeans.labels_ == hair_index, optimial_kmeans.labels_, optimial_kmeans.labels_ != hair_index)]
```

### Expected result

```
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
.....
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[255 255 255]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
[101  98  88]
```

Just keeping [101  98  88], other will be changed to [255 255 255].
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I misuse the `np.where` function.

As I just want to change all the values to [255, 255, 255] except [101, 98, 88]. My condition should be the `value` but not the `label`. So below code can perform what I wish.

```
np.where(X_compressed != [101, 98, 88], [255, 255, 255], X_compressed)
```